# Text distorsion on windows 8.1 application

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

So i made this application in c# using VS13 (http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/app/headphone-burn-in/09be1874-04ea-4dc8-90c3-c8a164369e7b) it was made for a "school" "competition", on my laptop with 1366x768 and lower resolution there are no bugs though a friend of mine tested this on a 1920x1080p display and got this bug http://prntscr.com/3pxhlt.

I had problems with lower resolutions too then i used viewbox, viewbox seemed to fix the problems but the higher resolution problem remains still.
My xaml code:

```
  <Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="auto" Width="auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
    <Grid x:Name="Main_Grid" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Width="1366" Height="768" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <EntranceThemeTransition/>
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Back button and page title -->
        <Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="auto" Width="auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.RowSpan="2" >
        <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.501,0.529" Margin="0,5,0,623" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="121"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="backButton" Margin="8,59,0,0" Command="{Binding NavigationHelper.GoBackCommand, ElementName=pageRoot}"
                    Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    AutomationProperties.Name="Back"
                    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="BackButton"
                    AutomationProperties.ItemType="Navigation Button" Grid.Column="1" Height="41" Width="46"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle" Text="Headphone Burn In" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" Grid.Column="1" 
                    IsHitTestVisible="false" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="223,0,423,41" SelectionChanged="pageTitle_SelectionChanged" FontFamily="Razer Header Regular" FontWeight="Normal" Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <TextBlock.Foreground>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF04DDFF" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </TextBlock.Foreground>
            </TextBlock>

    </Grid>
        </Viewbox>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="263" Margin="352,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="12" Width="575" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <Run Text="This application is made to optimize your headphones, the term &quot;Burn-in&quot; is used by Audiophiles and Sound &quot;geeks&quot; around the globe."/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <Run Foreground="#FF04DDFF" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" Text="How it works:"/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <Run Text="The application will play a variety of sounds including: White noise, Pink noise, Brown noise, High frequency sweeps, Low frequency sweeps."/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <Run Text="The Theory is that headphones from factory need some &quot;Playtime&quot; till they start sound as best as they are supposed to, the optimal play time is rumored to be around 40~50 hours of sound output."/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <Run Text="We choose to use "/>
        <Run FontFamily="Segoe UI, Tahoma, Arial, Arial Unicode MS, Microsoft Sans Serif, Lucida Sans Unicode" Text="White noise, Pink noise, Brown noise, High frequency sweeps, Low frequency sweeps for better results."/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <Run Foreground="#FF04DDFF" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" FontFamily="Segoe UI, Tahoma, Arial, Arial Unicode MS, Microsoft Sans Serif, Lucida Sans Unicode" Text="How to use:"/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <Run FontFamily="Segoe UI, Tahoma, Arial, Arial Unicode MS, Microsoft Sans Serif, Lucida Sans Unicode" Text="Insert your headphones to your device headphone jack, adjust your PC volume to 50% or just tune it so your headphones are not too loud, it's your preference."/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <Run Foreground="#FFE22F1D" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" FontFamily="Segoe UI, Tahoma, Arial, Arial Unicode MS, Microsoft Sans Serif, Lucida Sans Unicode" Text="Much loudness can hurt your Headphones/IEMs."/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <Run FontFamily="Segoe UI, Tahoma, Arial, Arial Unicode MS, Microsoft Sans Serif, Lucida Sans Unicode" Text="Press the Start button and insert your preferred runtime duration in the textbox between 1 minute to 999 minutes, then press the start button, the application will run the burn-in process for the selected amount of time, to force stop the test press the stop button or simply exit this application. "/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <Run Foreground="#FFE22F1D" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" FontFamily="Segoe UI, Tahoma, Arial, Arial Unicode MS, Microsoft Sans Serif, Lucida Sans Unicode" Text="This application won't run while minimized due to some policy matter."/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <Run Foreground="#FF04DDFF" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" FontFamily="Segoe UI, Tahoma, Arial, Arial Unicode MS, Microsoft Sans Serif, Lucida Sans Unicode"/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <Run Foreground="#FF04DDFF" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" FontFamily="Segoe UI, Tahoma, Arial, Arial Unicode MS, Microsoft Sans Serif, Lucida Sans Unicode" Text=""/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <Run Foreground="#FF04DDFF" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" FontFamily="Segoe UI, Tahoma, Arial, Arial Unicode MS, Microsoft Sans Serif, Lucida Sans Unicode"/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <Run Foreground="#FF04DDFF" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" FontFamily="Segoe UI, Tahoma, Arial, Arial Unicode MS, Microsoft Sans Serif, Lucida Sans Unicode"/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <Run Foreground="#FF04DDFF" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" FontFamily="Segoe UI, Tahoma, Arial, Arial Unicode MS, Microsoft Sans Serif, Lucida Sans Unicode"/>
        </TextBlock>
        <Button Content="Start" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="349,261,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderBrush="#FF04DDFF" Click="Button_Click" Height="48" Width="76" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Button Content="About" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="756,261,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderBrush="#FFE2A31D" Height="48" Click="Button_Click_2" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Button Content="Exit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="854,261,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderBrush="#FFE22F1D" Click="Button_Click_1" Height="48" Width="76" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by distortion or include an image of the "undistorted" version of the UI? Also, it doesn't seem to be a question about Metro design language. I'll retag.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i found the problem the original app was using a razer font, when used on a pc without it it made that effect i posted, i will just include my ttf on my app.